# Resharper pattern for case sensitive string comparison

Tags: .net, resharper, pattern-matching

I'm trying to add a Resharper pattern into the Pattern Catalog for string comparison.  Ultimately, I'd like it to warn me when I bump into code like `string1 == string2` and prompt me to replace it with `string1.Equals(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.  From here, I can change it to the appropriate case, but the initial step of forcing the use of Equals with the comparison options makes the intent of the comparison more obvious.

I can do this by creating a Search pattern:

```
$string1$ == $string2$
```

And creating a Replace pattern:

```
$string1$.Equals($string2$, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Where both $string1$ and $string2$ are "Expressions" of type "String (or derived type)".  This is a great start, because even if I wanted it to be a case sensitive search, I see the options and will change them.

The problem I'm having is that now it also warns me on `string == null`.  Is there any way to make it exclude `null` in the search?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Navigation_and_Search__SSR__Searching_for_Code_with_Pattern.html) it is not possible to set conditions like "is not null" on these expressions.

If you feel brave, you could first replace

```
$string$ == null
```

with

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty($string$)
```

where appropriate. But it does *not* mean exactly the same thing.